# SQLAlchemy, reflection, different backends and table/column case insensitivity

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, reflection, sqlalchemy

**Intro:** I'm writing web interface with SQLAlchemy reflection that supports multiple databases. It turns out that authors of application defined postgresql with lowercase tables/columns, eg. *job.jobstatus* while sqlite has mixed case, eg *Job.JobStatus*. I'm using *DeclarativeReflectedBase* from examples to combine reflection and declarative style.

**The issue:** Configure SQLAlchemy to work with tables/columns case insensitive with reflection

**I have done so far:**

- I have changed *DeclarativeReflectedBase.prepare()* method to pass *quote=False* into Table.__init__

**What is left to be solved:**

- relationship definitions still has to obey case when configuring joins, like *primaryjoin="Job.JobStatus==Status.JobStatus"*.
- configure __tablename__ based on engine type

**The question:** Are my assumptions correct or is there more straightforward way? *Maybe* I could tell reflection to reflect everything lowercase and all problems are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd probably want to look into defining a ".key" on each Column that's in lower case, that way you can refer to columns as lower case within application code.    You should use the column_reflect event (See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#schema-events) to define this key as a lower case version of the .name.

then, when you reflect the table, I'd just do something like this:

```
def reflect_table(name, engine):
    if engine.dialect.name == 'postgresql':
        name = name.lower()
    return Table(name, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

my_table = reflect_table("MyTable", engine)
```

I think that might cover it.

Comment: Thanks! I will start digging.

Comment: don't you want the case preserved when you're talking to the sqlite database ?

Comment: Seems like I have to support mysql, which has mixed case identifiers. Let's try this your way :)

Comment: How would I specify key for columns, without specifying all columns in table definitions?

Comment: OK, seems like MySQL only has case sensitive tables, figure that one out also.

Comment: careful with that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Good point, saw that you look up that varibale when doing reflection.